# Netbeans 7.2 hangs in loading modules after updates!! ubuntu 12.04+ 32bits system

Tags: java, netbeans, startup, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

I recently updated Netbeans 7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. Downloading those updates took quite a long time and I had to download some packages manually, but this were probably some issues with my corporate network and proxy. When it finally finished successfully I was prompted to restart IDE and so I did. Startup showed up and I got message that some modules were in wrong versions and they must be disabled. I clicked "disable modules" and then startup hangs informing only "Loading modules...". Tried doing it few times but the result is always the same. Even tried reinstalling IDE but whole process looked the same.

Comment: When you re-installed, did you do a complete removal of all .netbeans and .netbeans-registration files?

Comment: I had the same problem very recently, with the PL/SQL plugin. Your netbeans installation is choking on one of your updates. You'll only find out which one by a process of elimination. Don't bunch your module updates into one install, do it one by one to find out the offending update